# IIS 7 Application Pool Crash how to debug

Tags: iis-7, application-pools, windbg

We have several websites configured on our windows server 2012  and we noticed that one site seems crashing intermittently and the only way to get back this online is to restart that particular site and for some reason recycle application pool seems not helping the site to come online. Can some one point me to how we can diagnose this problem as i tried to use debug diagnostic tool but couldn't find the root cause of the issue but  here is the exception analysis i recieved using !analyze -v command . can any one point me how we can diagnose this issue on the production server

The actual exception we seeing on the server is `Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException`

and here is the details from `windbug`

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for PerfMon64.dll - 
Failed calling InternetOpenUrl, GLE=12029

FAULTING_IP: 
+a48e930
00000000`00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000000000019f8

PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
OS Thread Id: 0x19f8 (0)
Current frame: 
Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_LOG_FILL_PATTERN_ffffffff

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_LOG_FILL_PATTERN_ffffffff

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_LOG_FILL_PATTERN_ffffffff

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00007ffdb32a1118 to 00007ffdb5ea079a

STACK_TEXT:  
000000b1`a5e5f598 00007ffd`b32a1118 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xa
000000b1`a5e5f5a0 00007ffd`a3554a52 : 000000b1`a62ba7d0 000000b1`a5e5f6e0 00007ff7`00000000 00000000`000001c0 : KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x94
000000b1`a5e5f640 00007ff7`5eff20ca : 00000000`fffffffe 000000b1`a62b6cb0 000000b1`a5e5f780 000000b1`a62b6cb0 : w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+0x152
000000b1`a5e5f680 00007ff7`5eff392d : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : w3wp!wmain+0x40e
000000b1`a5e5f820 00007ffd`b3b313d2 : 00007ff7`5eff39a4 00007ff7`5e38f000 00007ff7`5e38f000 00000000`00000000 : w3wp!ParseCommandLine+0xbd5
000000b1`a5e5f860 00007ffd`b5e254f4 : 00007ffd`b3b313b0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
000000b1`a5e5f890 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+152
00007ffd`a3554a52 f605ffcb000003  test    byte ptr [w3wphost!g_dwDebugFlags (00007ffd`a3561658)],3

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+152

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: w3wphost

IMAGE_NAME:  w3wphost.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  582757e0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_LOG_FILL_PATTERN_ffffffff_80000003_w3wphost.dll!AppHostInitialize

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_LOG_FILL_PATTERN_ffffffff_w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+152

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/w3wp_exe/8_5_9600_16384/5215df96/unknown/0_0_0_0/bbbbbbb4/80000003/00000000.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Thanks

Comment: Too much experience is required, so if you cannot easily follow posts like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/04/27/asp-net-2-0-crash-case-study-unhandled-exceptions/ please do open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to save your time.

Comment: I have raised a ticket with Microsoft and will post here with what response i get from Microsoft. Many Thanks